# Send multiple application protocols requests ( Similar to mailto: )

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, header, protocols

I work with an application that has created it's own protocol such like MS did for its MSN client `msnim:chat?contact=test@test.com`

However, I need to create a PHP or javascript (or combo) to basically send 3 requests to the protocol as soon as possible. I also want it if the end result is `www.test.com/send.php` that a user link `<a href='www.test.com/send.php'>` would not pop up or redirect to a page much like doing

`<?php header('Location: msnim:chat?contact=test@test.com'); ?>` would not create a new page or redirect upon user click of href

Here is a JQUERY and JSBin of my proof of concept

http://jsbin.com/etubas/11/

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("a#click_me").click(function(){
        setTimeout(function(){
            console.log('test ran');
            window.location = 'mailto:test@test.com';
        }, 100);
        setTimeout(function(){
            console.log('new ran');
            window.location = 'mailto:new@new.com';
        }, 200);
    });
});
```

This seems to work OK with IE9 and as far as I can see IE8. Firefox 10 seems be OK too but chrome 17 only does 1st email.

Edit 1: Updated with MSN instead of AIM links to be more universal for testing, and include jquery example and JSbin

Edit 2: Updated to mailto links

Comment: So, what's the question? You have a proposed solution, it seems, but haven't stated any problems with it.

Comment: So what does your JSBin *not* do which you want it to?

Comment: Oh, well it's not a proof of concept then, is it? :-) I'll update my answer, but I believe iFrames are the answer.

Comment: @BHare: I don't understand why you have to go through PHP - do you do some tracking etc.? Otherwise I'm assuming that's optional

Comment: @BHare: problem on newer versions of Chrome occurs because of a security violation; there is only one navigation action allowed per user interaction (i.e. click) - rerouting the same event to fire again or setting a long timeout doesn't help

Answer (score 10):

The following HTML/JavaScript code will observe clicks on `<a id="click_me">` and create two new iFrames to a URL which can trigger the custom URI scheme you created:

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){

    var imURL = 'http://josh.gitlin.name/9472703.php?id='; // Change this to your URL

    function openIM(who) {
        var iFrame = '<iframe src="'+imURL+who+'"></iframe>';
        $('div#imLinks').append(iFrame);
    }

    $("a#click_me").click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        setTimeout(function(){
            openIM('1');
        }, 100);
        setTimeout(function(){
            openIM('2');
        }, 200);
    });
});​
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <p>Some content here</p>
    <p><a href="#" id="click_me">Click Me!</a></p>
    <div id="imLinks"></div>
</body>
</html>​
```

The following PHP code is what will be displayed inside those iFrames:

```
<?php

$screenname = '';

switch($_REQUEST['id']) {
        case '1': $screenname = 'firstPerson'; break;
        case '2': $screenname = 'secondPerson'; break;
        default: $screenname = 'otherPerson'; break;
}

echo <<<END_OF_HTML 
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0;url=aim:goim?screenname=$screenname">
</head>
</html>
END_OF_HTML;
```

[Tested under Safari and Chrome](http://jsfiddle.net/yKGGU/), this will open up multiple IM windows when the link is clicked. Obviously tweak to your satisfaction.

Comment: Nice approach but it's not working on the software I am using, nor mailto: links. Here is my JSBIN demostrating mailto: links http://jsbin.com/eborog/6/edit

Comment: That works for me under Firefox, Safari, and Chrome @BHare... the only thing which doesn't work is that the link gets followed and the second email doesn't open due to that. If you [prevent the default action](http://jsbin.com/eborog/7) that should solve that...

Comment: Weird, I can't get it to work with chrome, I havent bothered with ff or ie yet. Running chrome 17 windows 7 premium 64 bit: Video of it not working here: http://www.screenr.com/wwT8  (this is with your prevent default)

Comment: Hmmmmm... It's probably either a Windows issue or an Outlook issue. I tested using Chrome/Safari/Firefox and Thunderbird under OS X. Does it work for you if you use `goim:` URIs instead of `mailto:` UIRs?

Comment: It has the same effect using the `aim:` protocol. Curiously, it works in IE with both `mailto:` and `aim:`. I tried in firefox and at first it worked but then it would so the same as chrome and only give me the first one.

Comment: Well, it looks like my answer won't fully work for you. I wonder what the problem is... I'll see if I can reproduce the issue and if I can, I'll see if I can fix it.

Comment: @Josh: +1 for appropriate use of iframes

Answer (score 8):

### Update:

As BHare points out, none of the "multiple popup" approaches seem to work in the latest versions of Chrome. The reason behind that is their detection of "user-initiated" actions as opposed to potentially malicious flooding of user screens with unwanted windows.

In essence, Chrome would allow you to trigger no more than one pop-up per click event. The click event also has to be unique so it cannot trigger a handler that will show popup #1, propagate to the parent and trigger another handler that will show popup #2 etc.

Another failed attempt was made by attempting to distribute the popups (main page initiates popup A that initiates popup B that initiates popup C etc.) - this was recognized as a non-user-initiated action and only one protocol call was ultimately allowed.

It is unfortunate that this behaviour is not controlled by an editable policy, i.e. it cannot be adjusted by allowing popups based on the origin domain.

Depending on deployment specifics (i.e. intranet vs. internet) you may be able to code an extension for Chrome that would [initiate the popups at chrome level](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/tabs.html) (meaning *browser chrome*, effectively any content/style/script that exists *outside* and above any individual page). Your page can, in turn, detect custom add-on availability and have your "triple links" channelled through to that extension, or prompt the end-user to have the add-on installed. Seeing how you're unable to modify the behaviour of target protocol links (by, for instance, combining the instructions into a single call similar to that of **href="mailto:first@email.com,second@email.com,third@email.com"**) this may be the only option available to you at this stage.

### Original answer:

Protocol-specific link would work just as well on the client-side without *ever* going to the server; you can just add an iframe(s) at runtime with correct src set.

First, let's take good care of the markup. It's demeaning having to manually assign urls to click functions. I've done it the first way that worked and made sense (at the price of html validation), but you could be neater and use custom data-* attributes:

```
<a href="mailto:first@tempinbox.com" href2="mailto:second@tempinbox.com" href3="mailto:third@tempinbox.com">Click me!</a>​
```

You know what else is demeaning? Having to manually bind click functions - it just takes too much effort. *And what if there were two anchors like that?* Let's just tell jQuery to bind the click event to every link that uses this protocol:

```
$('a[href^="mailto:"]').bind("click", function(e){
    /*Do stuff*/
});
```

Before we iterate over the **href~href3** attributes, let's write a function that will handle opening individual mailto links:

```
function openMailto(s){
    if (s) $("<iframe />", {src:s, class:"mailto-iframe"}).appendTo("body");
}
```

It checks that the url is passed from a non-empty attribute, dynamically creates an iframe element and maps attributes to it and "runs" it by appending to body.

Completed here: http://jsfiddle.net/uaLVh/ - extra bonuses include some css to hide helper iframes and to style protocol-specific links. And yes, I know I promised to iterate over href attribures but I've just done it manually.

**html**

```
<a href="#">Don't click me</a><br/>
<a href="mailto:first@tempinbox.com" href2="mailto:second@tempinbox.com" href3="mailto:third@tempinbox.com">Click me!</a>​
```

**css**

```
/*prevent these iframes from being visible*/
iframe.mailto-iframe{display:none;}

/*bonus: style your protocol-specific links*/
a[href^="mailto:"] {padding-left:20px;background:url(http://sstatic.net/stackoverflow/img/favicon.ico) no-repeat;}
​
```

**js**

```
$('a[href^="mailto:"]').bind("click", function(e){
    //cache "this" link element jquery reference
    $this=$(this);

    //remove "helper" iframes if any, you don't want to end up with 300 iframes by accident!
    $("iframe.mailto-iframe").remove();

    //go wild... you could have a nice loop as you're not limited to 3 hrefs
    openMailto($this.attr("href"));
    openMailto($this.attr("href2"));
    openMailto($this.attr("href3"));

    //processing href2 and href3 before allowing the default action to happen firstseemed counter-intuitive
    e.preventDefault();
    return false;
});
function openMailto(s){
    if (s) $("<iframe />", {src:s, class:"mailto-iframe"}).appendTo("body");
}
```

Comment: First off let me thank you for taking out the time to construct such a beautiful and simple response. Your solution will indeed add to anyone looking at this message in the future for reference. However in my specific case, chrome is not working still with your example. I even tried chrome dev channel.  Proof: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=A9yLw4c_JTM

Comment: @BHare: I managed to reproduce the issue on Mac Chrome - as far as I can tell it's caused by security restriction of user-initiated location changes (i.e. one click = one change not three). My question is, **are you able to achieve this functionality by modifying the protocol link?** For instance you could do href="mailto:first@email.com,second@email.com,third@email.com"; would the protocol used by your application support similar syntax? That would effectively discard the need for multiple iframes etc.

Comment: Nope, if it would then my life would be ALOT easier.

Comment: I suppose Ill just have to put "Not working in chrome" when its clicked and they have chrome. I was hoping someone would know of an alternative method that would work for chrome.